# Possibility to setTooltip on NSBezierPath

Tags: cocoa, nsbezierpath

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a tooltip on a drawn `NSBezierPath`.

Why I'm asking this is the following: I'm adding shapes in the form of `NSRect` to the view. These rects represent periods of history. It would be amazing to see the start year of the period together with the end year.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible since there is no class method of `NSBezierPath` that supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NSView that contains your bezier paths, call [`-addToolTipRect:owner:userData:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/addToolTipRect%3aowner%3auserData%3a) for each tooltip you want to add. The [`-bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/bounds) method on each path will give you the bounding rect.